# How do you pass the value of a variable to a different call in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase

I have an object `test`, with fields `a` and `b` that have nested properties say:

```
test = {a: {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3'},
       {b: {key1: 'value4', key2: 'value5', key3: 'value6'}}
```

I want to be  able to change the  nested values inside either `a` or `b`, but have the one I'm changing be variable. For clarity, I want to be able to do something like:

```
test.$i$.key1: 'value10'
```

where `$i$` refers to the value that `i` holds, in this case either `a` or `b`.

Is that possible?

I am aware that this is easily solved with bracket notation, but this will not work in my situation.

Copied from firebase docs:

```
// Create an initial document to update.
var frankDocRef = db.collection("users").doc("frank");
frankDocRef.set({
    name: "Frank",
    favorites: { food: "Pizza", color: "Blue", subject: "recess" },
    age: 12
});

// To update age and favorite color:
db.collection("users").doc("frank").update({
    "age": 13,
    "favorites.color": "Red"
})
.then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully updated!");
});
```

I want to be able to do:

```
const var1 = 'color'
db.collection("users").doc("frank").update({
    "age": 13,
    "favorites.$var1$": "Red"
})
```

where $var1$ refers to the value that $va1r$ holds, in this case either `food`, `color` or `subject`.

Bracket notation does not work in this case, as I am passing a string to firebase, which it doesn't interpret like that.

Comment: use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) `test[a].key1`

Comment: use bracket `test[i].key1`

Answer (score 2):

You can access property of an object dynamically using **Bracket notation**.

Try the below code:

```js
var test = {
  a: {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2',
    key3: 'value3'
  },
  b: {
    key1: 'value4',
    key2: 'value5',
    key3: 'value6'
  }
};

var key = 'a';
console.log(test[key].key1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use a [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
const var1 = 'color'
db.collection("users").doc("frank").update({
    "age": 13,
    ["favorites." + var1]: "Red"
})
```

Or construct the object "outside" of the update call:

```
const var1 = 'color'

const data = { "age": 13 };
data["favorites." + var1] = "Red";

db.collection("users").doc("frank").update(data)
```